# Can I directly stream from HttpResponseMessage to file without going through memory?

Tags: c#, stream, asp.net-web-api2

My program uses `HttpClient` to send a GET request to a Web API, and this returns a file.

I now use this code (simplified) to store the file to disc:

```
public async Task<bool> DownloadFile()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var uri = new Uri("http://somedomain.com/path");
    var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var fileName = response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
        using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\test\" + fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now, when this code runs, the process loads all of the file into memory. I actually would rather expect the stream gets streamed from the `HttpResponseMessage.Content` to the `FileStream`, so that only a small portion of it is held in memory.

We are planning to use that on large files (> 1GB), so is there a way to achieve that without having all of the file in memory?

Ideally without manually looping through reading a portion to a `byte[]` and writing that portion to the file stream until all of the content is written?

Comment: look at - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.hosting.ihostbufferpolicyselector(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: `CopyToAsync` is already doing what you describe (internally it repeatedly reads a chunk of data from the response and writes it to the file until all data is transferred) it should not result in buffering the entire file to memory at once.

Comment: Thats what I thought too, however looking at the memory consumption it definetly does load the whole file in memory, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Have you tried `response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()` and use `Stream.CopyToAsync`?

Comment: Then it may be that your measurement of "memory consumption" is inaccurate. The runtime will not necessarily release memory that is "free" unless it needs to, so the memory usage values in e.g. Task Manager may not reflect the memory actually "in use" by the application.

Comment: That is also likley not the case, as when I debug its terminated by an out of memory exception very soon.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It looks like this is by-design - if you check the documentation for `HttpClient.GetAsync()` you'll see it says:

> The returned task object will complete after the whole response
>   (**including content**) is read

You can instead use `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync()` which specifically states:

> This method does not buffer the stream.

However you *don't* then get access to the headers in the response as far as I can see. Since that's presumably a requirement (as you're getting the file name from the headers), then you may want to use `HttpWebRequest` instead which allows you you to get the response details (headers etc.) without reading the whole response into memory. Something like:

```
public async Task<bool> DownloadFile()
{
    var uri = new Uri("http://somedomain.com/path");
    var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

    ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition;
    var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(response.Headers["Content-Disposition"], out contentDisposition)
        ? contentDisposition.FileName
        : "noname.dat";
    using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\test\" + fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        await response.GetResponseStream().CopyToAsync(fs);
    }

    return true
}
```

Note that if the request returns an unsuccessful response code an exception will be thrown, so you may wish to wrap in a `try..catch` and return `false` in this case as in your original example.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Indeed, using GetStreamAsync on the client allows saving the stream directly to disk and not to memory. Since we have control over the server too, I can simply fetch the metadata (file name, size) in a separate request first. Then I don't need to access the headers.

Answer (score 17):

Instead of `GetAsync(Uri)` use the the `GetAsync(Uri, HttpCompletionOption)` overload with the `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` value.

The same applies to `SendAsync` and other methods of `HttpClient`

Sources:

- docs (see remarks) 
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=netcore-1.1#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_GetAsync_System_Uri_System_Net_Http_HttpCompletionOption_

> The returned Task object will complete based on the completionOption parameter **after the part or** all of the response (including content) is read.

- .NET Core implementation of `GetStreamAsync` that uses `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/release/1.1.0/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L163-L168
- [HttpClient spike in memory usage with large response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44310239)
- [HttpClient.GetStreamAsync() with custom request?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47513400) (don't mind the comment on response, the `ResponseHeadersRead` is what does the trick)

Answer (score -1):

Another simple and quick way to do it is:

```
public async Task<bool> DownloadFile(string url)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
       new HttpClient().GetStreamAsync(webPath).Result.CopyTo(ms);
       
       ... // use ms in what you want 
    }
}
```

now you have the file downloaded as stream in ms.

Comment: OP specifically asked for a way to circumvent streaming the entire file to memory.