# HttpClient.GetStreamAsync() with custom request?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, stream, portable-class-library, dotnet-httpclient

My goal is to use the `HttpClient` class to make a web-request so that I can write the response to a file (after parsing). Therefore I need the result as a `Stream`.

[HttpClient.GetStreamAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551738(v=vs.118).aspx) only takes the string `requestUri` as parameter. So there is no possibility to create a request with custom `HttpRequestHeader`, custom `HttpMethod`, custom *ContentType*, custom content and so on?

I saw that `HttpWebRequest` is sometimes [used instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033927/can-i-directly-stream-from-httpresponsemessage-to-file-without-going-through-mem), but in my PCL (Profile111) there is no `Add` method for the [`Headers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.webheadercollection(v=vs.110).aspx). So can I use `HttpClient`, should I use `HttpWebRequest` instead or should I use another class/library at all?

Comment: Have a look at the `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders` and set your headers through there

Comment: You can always use `SendAsync` and just read the stream content.

Comment: @Crowcoder: `SendAsync` returns `HttpResponseMessage`. How to stream the content here?

Comment: @testing - via `.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Thanks for the tip. Is the response completely hold in memory then and afterwards converted to a stream? I want to keep the memory footprint as low as possible, because I deal with larger files here.

Comment: @testing a stream is aptly named as it "streams" the data to you, it is not buffered first but you will eventually end up with the entire set of data. If you are able to process partial files in some way then you can ask the server for ranges of bytes [if it supports it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests)

Comment: @Crowcoder: What are the impacts of *"you will eventually end up with the entire set of data"*? Does this depend on the OS? At some time the file has to be in memory, except you use ranges?

Comment: @testing, it usually happens so fast that you don't notice or don't care. You can generally treat it as a regular return value from a method call. I just mean "eventually" in computer time. Where you would care is something like an open socket connection that continuously sends stock ticker updates or something like that. You might use ranges if the memory consumption is too high for the web server, you can aggregate the bytes and process the file in another process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`GetStreamAsync` is just a shortcut for building and sending a content-less GET request. Doing it the "long way" is fairly straightforward:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.???, uri);
// add Content, Headers, etc to request
request.Content = new StringContent(yourJsonString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

Comment: ~~Awaiting the `SendAsync` call as you've provided causes the whole response to be read into memory for me. Using `await client.GetStreamAsync(url);` allows me to hand off the stream without the whole response being placed into memory. When I snapshot the heap before and after I can see all 60+MB of the downloaded file in memory where as in the latter the heap only increases by 5 or so MB.~~ Missed the HttpCompletionOption!

Comment: This does not work as mentioned when reading large streams, or server side events (SSE) where the connection never gets closed. It will just get stuck on the SendAsync method and never continue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned being open to using a different library, here's an alternative that uses [Flurl](https://flurl.io) (disclaimer: I'm the author). Say you want to POST some JSON data with a couple custom headers and receive a stream:

```
var stream = await "https://api.com"
    .WithHeaders(new { header1 = "value1", header2 = "value2" })
    .PostJsonAsync(data)
    .ReceiveStream();
```

Here `data` is just a POCO. Don't worry about serializing it to a JSON string or setting Content-Type to `application/json`; Flurl will do both for you.

Flurl uses `HttpClient` under the hood and targets .NET Standard 1.1, which is [fully compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) with PCL Profile111.